How can I make some version of exercises from a list and get the LaTeX file?
I have a list
list = {{{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 2}, {9, 3, 1}}, {{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 3}, {9, 
    1, 2}}, {{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 3}, {9, 2, 1}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7, 2, 
    3}, {8, 4, 5}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7, 2, 3}, {8, 5, 4}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7,2, 4}, {8, 3, 5}}}

and write the equation of the plane passing through three points of each element of list.
Table[{pA, pB, pC} = points;
 mylist = {pA, pB, pC, 
TraditionalForm[Subtract @@ Expand[CoplanarPoints[{pA, pB, pC, {x, y, z}}]]] == 0}, {points, list}]


I want to make some exercises in LaTeX like this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\begin{document}
  \begin{ex}
    The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6, 8, 5)$, $B(7, 4, 2)$, $C(9, 3, 1)$ is $ x-5 y+7 z-1=0$.
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6, 8, 5)$, $B(7, 4, 3)$, $C(9, 1, 2)$ is $ 2 x+3 y-5 z-11=0$.
  \end{ex}  
  \begin{ex}
    The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6, 8, 5)$, $B(7, 4, 3)$, $C(9, 2,1)$ is $ 2 x-y+3 z-19=0$.
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6, 9, 1)$, $B(7, 2, 3)$, $C(8, 4, 5)$ is $ 2 x-z-11=0$.
  \end{ex}      
\end{document}


How can I tell Mathematica to do this?

Code below generates

The LaTeX generated by Mathematica is
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{ex}
The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6,8,5)$, $B(7,4,2)$, $C(9,3,1)$ is $x-5 y+7 z-1=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6,8,5)$, $B(7,4,3)$, $C(9,1,2)$ is $2 x+3 y-5 z-11=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6,8,5)$, $B(7,4,3)$, $C(9,2,1)$ is $2 x-y+3 z-19=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6,9,1)$, $B(7,2,3)$, $C(8,4,5)$ is $2 x-z-11=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6,9,1)$, $B(7,2,3)$, $C(8,5,4)$ is $13 x-y-10 z-59=0$
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
The equation of the plane passing through three points $A(6,9,1)$, $B(7,2,4)$, $C(8,3,5)$ is $5 x-y-4 z-17=0$
\end{ex}
\end{document}

Code from clean kernel
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
list = {{{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 2}, {9, 3, 1}}, {{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 3}, {9, 
    1, 2}}, {{6, 8, 5}, {7, 4, 3}, {9, 2, 1}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7, 2, 
    3}, {8, 4, 5}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7, 2, 3}, {8, 5, 4}}, {{6, 9, 1}, {7,
     2, 4}, {8, 3, 5}}};

data = Table[{pA, pB, pC} = points;
  mylist = {pA, pB, pC, 
    Subtract @@ Expand[CoplanarPoints[{pA, pB, pC, {x, y, z}}]] == 
     0}, {points, list}]

toX[e_]:=StringReplace[ToString[TeXForm[e]],{"\\}"->")","\\{"->"("}]

fileName=FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"my_HW.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName],DeleteFile[fileName]];
file=OpenWrite[fileName,PageWidth->Infinity];
WriteString[file,"\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n"<>
"\\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}\n"<>
"\\usepackage{amsmath}\n"<>
"\\usepackage{amsthm}\n"<>
"\\theoremstyle{definition}\n"<>
"\\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}\n"<>
"\\begin{document}\n"];
Do[WriteString[file,"\\begin{ex}\n"<>
"The equation of the plane passing through three points $A"<>
  toX[data[[n,1]]] <>"$, $B"<>toX[data[[n,2]]]<>
  "$, $C"<>toX[data[[n,3]]]<>"$ is $"<>toX[data[[n,4]]]<>
"$\n\\end{ex}\n"],{n,1,Length@data}
];
WriteString[file,"\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]


Does your code support Vietnamese?

@JohnPaulPeter , Yes, Latex handle other langauges,  Add \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and \usepackage[vietnam,english]{babel} to the preamble. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40482/typesetting-any-language-vietnamese-for-example   But the question is how to enter Vietnamese Language as string inside the notebook in Mathematica itself. I could not do it. Mathematica messes up the string when writing it to the file using WriteString. So this is the issue to solve. But Latex itself can handle other languages and even mixed ones inside same document.

@JohnPaulPeter You could make separate question asking how to write Vietnamese in string in Mathematica and save it to file without the characters getting missed up. I am sure someone will know how. If there is a way, then you can adopt it to the above code.

If I want to use data[[n,1]] in stead of  $A"<>toX[data[[n,2]]]<>"$ and data[[n,2]] in stead of  $B"<>toX[data[[n,2]]]<>"$ to calculate data[[n,2]] - data[[n,1]]. How can I do that?

@JohnPaulPeter I do not understand. data[[n,1]] and data[[n,2]] need to be converted to Latex then to String to be written to file. If you do not want to do that, you can try replacing $A"<>toX[data[[n,1]]]<>"$ with just String[ data[[n,1]] ] and same for data[[n,2]] and see if this what you wanted.

i.e. do <>ToString[data[[n,1]]]<> instead. Same for all other ones

How can I use ToExpression to data[[n,1]] and data[[n,2]]?

@JohnPaulPeter There is no need to use ToExpression on data because data is already a Mathematica Expression. We use ToExpression on string to convert the string to a Mathematica expression. For example ToExpression["Sin[x]"] converts it to SIn[x]. But data is not string. It is already Mathematica expression as is.

Thank you very much.
